# .net core - how to access self-contained web app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a .net core web app and published it to a server. I'm new to this area, but I have heard it said that it being self-contained, I should be able to run the .exe on the server and access the web app externally. I have confirmed on both my local and on the server that the same runtime exists.

**The error I'm seeing**: the executable starts fine, but the moment I hit http://localhost:5000 on the server, there's a failure when it tries to grab HTTPContext.user.identity.name. It is empty. But regardless of this I still can't access this web app outside of the server.

Is it possible to run the .exe on said server and then access the web app by http://:5000? If so, how can you accomplish this?

Comment: how are you starting/running the exe?

Comment: You'll need to make sure your server accepts connections from outside over that port, so check your firewall.

Comment: @johnluke.laue as of right now i'm running the executable

Comment: @juunas - i have made an exception for the port. still no dice..

Comment: @TonyD. i mean if are running it though something like IIS (for example)?

Comment: @johnluke.laue - i started by trying to run through IIS. but because it's self contained, i was advised to just run it as a service running on the server

Comment: Is the app listening on e.g. `0.0.0.0:5000`? Depending on what it's listening affects how it can be accessed as well.

Comment: I think you should still be able to run it through IIS (like this guide points out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-the-iis-site)